# Magento AvS/FastSimpleImport not associating simple products to configurable product

Tags: php, magento

At the moment I'm facing some problems with the [AvS/FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) plugin for Magento 1.9.0.1.

When I try to import the set of data provided by the documentation, all the simple products are added, the configurable product is added to Magento. But when I try associate the simple products to the configurable product nothing will happen.

All data is imported well, like the images, prices, tier prices, stock etc. The only thing that not works is the association of the simple products.

On both server I described below I use Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

I'm running at the moment a webserver with PHP Version 5.4.41 and as Server API I am using FPM/FastCGI. This is the new server. (On this server I have the problem)

On the old server with PHP Version 5.4.27 and Server API Apache 2.0 Handler I didn't had this problem.

```
$data = array(
        array(
        'sku' => 'simple1',
        '_type' => 'simple',
        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
        '_product_websites' => 'base',
        'name' => 'Simple Product 1',
        'description' => 'Default',
        'short_description' => 'Default',
        'price' => 10,
        'weight' => 0,
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        'tax_class_id' => 2,
        'qty' => 99,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'color' => 'red',
    ),
    array(
        'sku' => 'simple2',
        '_type' => 'simple',
        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
        '_product_websites' => 'base',
        'name' => 'Simple Product 2',
        'description' => 'Default',
        'short_description' => 'Default',
        'price' => 10,
        'weight' => 0,
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        'tax_class_id' => 2,
        'qty' => 99,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'color' => 'green',
    ),
    array(
        'sku' => 'configurable',
        '_type' => 'configurable',
        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
        '_product_websites' => 'base',
        'price' => 10,
        'name' => 'Configurable Product',
        'description' => 'Default',
        'short_description' => 'Default',
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        'tax_class_id' => 2,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        '_super_products_sku' => array('simple1', 'simple2'),
        '_super_attribute_code' => 'color',
    ),
);

try {
    /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
    $import
        ->setUseNestedArrays(true)
        ->processProductImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
};
```

When I run the script, no errors will occur and the import says it is completed. When I try the sample code of grouped and bundled products everything will works.

Could it be the problem is caused by the different Server API otherwise I don't have any idea why my simple products not are associated with the configurable products.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With special thanks to [Sh3rman](https://github.com/Sh3rman), I found a temporary solution for this problem.

The solution is to disable the Flat Catalog Product.
(System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog: Use Flat Catalog Product = No).

For more information please look at the answer of [Sh3rman on GitHub](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/232#issuecomment-107834726)